# If controller stop loop instead of creating new iteration - Jmeter Groovy

Tags: loops, if-statement, groovy, jmeter, beanshell

I have an issue that I am trying to solve,
I have a loop controller and inside it I created if controller.
I want something to be done if the "if controller" is true.
the condition is that:
def loop_counter2 = ${__counter(TRUE)}; 
and the if controller condition is "${loop_counter2}" == "1".
the loop is set to run 3 times, so the expected results is that the condition will be correct only once.
I have 2 problems
1. the condition never set true for some reason
2. the loop is performed only once and not as set to 3 (I print the loop counter to Jmeter consul and only 1 displayed).
Can someone please advise why this is happening?
if I remove the If controller the loop performed 3 times

Check Arr - the loop controller that I want to run 3 times regardless what in the if controller. 
test2 - put in variable (loop_counter2) the number of the loop iteration
if controller - the if controller that should be true only once, when we in iteration 1
JSR223 SAMPLER - Print to consul if entered to if controller

P.S all the purpose of my test is to run 3 times and if condition is set to connect DB.
in Java for example I can use for loop and put if condition inside.

```
  for (i = 0;i<3;i++)
    {
     if (i = 1)
       print happy;
    else nothing;
    }

how can I perform it in Jmeter?
```

how can I perform this in Jmeter?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, any feedback on answer ? If ok it should be marked as OK and upvoted so that others can use it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it:

[image]

Use a [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) element configured this way:

[image]

And [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) will be (I use [__jexl3](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) function and check "Interpret Condition as Variable expression" for performances reason):

[image]